# I want to add one PDF2 file in between the another PDF1 file by using ITEXTSHARP

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

PDF2 is small file and PDF1 is the large file. I want PDF2 is adding to in B/w the PDF1 file, where i want to add, goto add that place. for example i have 50 page PDF file, another PDF file is 3 pages. this 3 pages ADDING to 45th page of 50 pages PDF file. i want page number that 3 pages as 45-(1), 45-(2), 45-(3). like this manner

Comment: And how far have you got so far? What is the problem that stopped you?

Comment: atleast tell the answer for add one pdf to another pdf file. that means combining to pdf files in to one file

Comment: Use `PdfCopy` to copy the pages from your source document in the order you want, c.f. the sample [iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/Concatenate.cs](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/Concatenate.cs)

Comment: i don't have kuujinbo s/w. i am using itext sharp

Comment: *i don't have kuujinbo s/w. i am using itext sharp* - and so does the sample.